# Determining the limits of the following functions...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure about the limits of the following two functions.
For the first one, I think it doesn't have a limit. For the second one, I get the number 3. 
Correct me if I'm wrong...

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sin^2 x+3x^3}{x^2+x^3}$$
I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so please find the question by clicking the links above...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the $|\sin x|$ for positive number near zero equal $\sin x$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}=1$$

$$\\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sin^2 x+3x^3}{x^2+x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sin^2 x/x^3+3x^3/x^3}{x^2/x^3+x^3/x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sin^2 x/x^3+3}{1/x+1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{0+3}{0+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 3 for your second limit.

For the first, note that as $x\to0$ from the right, $\sin x$ is positive and approaches 0.

Thus, $|\sin x|=\sin x$, since $\sin x$ is positive.

Therefore...
$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}=\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x}=1.$$